# Find cause of cpu-usage?

Tags: performance

Is there some way to find out, what in Emacs is causing spurious cpu usage?

Since a few days I notice Emacs retaining high CPU usage despite not being used actively, having no subprocesses, and not being in blocking state. `M-: (all-threads)` is empty, except for `(current-thread)`. I also wasn't able to reproduce the issue across sessions.

I am using Emacs on Windows 10, so many unix tools will not be applicable.

Comment: Setting `debug-on-quit` and hitting `C-g` when Emacs is maxing CPU might give a hint.

Comment: @npostavs – Sadly no. Whatever is using the CPU is doing it in a non-blocking manner. No hickups, that would indicate a time-window for pressing <kbd>C-g</kbd>. The only reason I noticed, was because the fan was spinning more than usual.

Comment: You can keep an eye on the Task Manager tray icon which would show when CPU usage is up.

Comment: @npostavs I have encountered the issue again today. `toggle-debug-on-quit` and `C-g` don't trigger the debugger. And since the CPU usage has incrased, it remains constantly at "11%" (one of 8 cores).

Comment: "`toggle-debug-on-quit` and `C-g` don't trigger the debugger" - not at all? Are you didn't toggle `debug-on-quit` off by accident?

Comment: I double checked, so no. Hammering `C-g` would trigger the debugger, if I executed some non-instantaneous command intentionally, but Emacs would happily ignore `C-g` and while using a CPU core. The confusing part, really, is why this isn't in any manner noticable during operation, by anything OTHER than fan-noise and CPU monitoring. I would expect spurious CPU-use to cause occasional hiccups.

Comment: Hmm, running with [profiling](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Profiling.html) *might* help, if the CPU maxing period is long enough to drown out the normal usage. Otherwise, I think the only thing left to do is run Emacs under gdb (which means installing MSYS and rebuilding with debug symbols)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@npostavs' last comment should give you enough hints to solve the problem. The built-in profiler can tell which function is causing the high CPU usage.

Here are simple steps to get started:

1. `M-x profiler-start RET`
2. select 'cpu'
3. wait for a few seconds
4. `M-x profiler-report RET`
5. modify emacs e.g. by disabling the conflicting mode
6. `M-x profiler-stop RET`
7. repeat to continue testing

More details in the [Profiling Emacs manual page](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Profiling.html).